# Routing generated paths in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm a beginner in ruby-on-rails and I spent my last hour trying to do the following thing:

I have a ruby-on-rails application - the blog with posts and categories. 
I want to have another URL for the posts (I would like to have `http://localhost:3000/news` instead of `http://localhost:3000/posts`) First I tried to replace the controller and classes from `Posts` to `News`, but I gave up(because of the annoyng singular-plural thing). Then in my I replaced `map.resources :posts` (case 1) to

```
  map.resources :news, :controller => "posts"     #case 2
```

or

```
  map.resources :posts, :as => 'news'             #case 3
```

in `routes.rb` as I saw on [some websites](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It doesn't work either.

How can I do this?

---

EDIT:

the output of `rake routes` is (only first lines):

for case 1 and 3:

```
               posts GET    /posts                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
     formatted_posts GET    /posts.:format                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                     POST   /posts                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
                     POST   /posts.:format                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
            new_post GET    /posts/new                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
  formatted_new_post GET    /posts/new.:format               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
 formatted_edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit.:format          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                post GET    /posts/:id                       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
      formatted_post GET    /posts/:id.:format               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                     PUT    /posts/:id                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                     PUT    /posts/:id.:format               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                     DELETE /posts/:id                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
                     DELETE /posts/:id.:format               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

the output for case 2:

```
           news_index GET    /news                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
 formatted_news_index GET    /news.:format                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                      POST   /news                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
                      POST   /news.:format                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
             new_news GET    /news/new                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
   formatted_new_news GET    /news/new.:format                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
            edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
  formatted_edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit.:format           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                 news GET    /news/:id                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
       formatted_news GET    /news/:id.:format                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                      PUT    /news/:id                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                      PUT    /news/:id.:format                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                      DELETE /news/:id                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
                      DELETE /news/:id.:format                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

I have errors in case 2, because in my sourcecode I don't have `edit_news`, I have for example `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>`

Comment: Could you add the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: What happens when you do `map.resources :posts, :as => 'news'` and try to access `/news`?

Comment: @Marcel, I added the outputs; @Alex, In that case I get `Routing Error - No route matches "/news" with {:method=>:get}`, but it works with `posts`.

Comment: Hm, okay. From what I see, everything should be working. Could you maybe add your `routes.rb` file as well? The only remaining issue I could think of is that the you didn't place the command correctly (like placing it behind the generic /:controller/:action lines or so).

Comment: @Marcel, it is the first line in the file (after `ActionController::Routing...`). If I understand correctly, should I rename all my old links from `edit_post_path(post)` to `edit_news_path(post)`? I tried, but what should I write at delete/show? Because I get an error like `undefined method 'post_path'`, but there isn't anything that contains 'post' (I renamed the variable in the for like this: `<% for news in @posts %>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step was good: replace all Post(s)* classes to News* classes. Calling your model News and controller NewsController should not be a problem. Make sure you find all occurrences, also in the code (also things like `post_path` should be replaced with `news_path`).

Next, modify your route to

```
map.resources :news
```

in order to use the NewsController instead of the PostsController. And it should work.

*Note*: Do not forget to restart your webserver.

Comment: I did like you said, but I had to add `:singular => :news_instance` in `routes.rb` and replace `new_news_path` to `new_news_instance_path`. There are still some problems left to fix. But I don't know why the example with `productos` on this page doesn't work: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000522

Answer (score 6):

The word "news" has ambiguity between singular (member) and plural (collection) names. You could try working around this, but you might just end up confusing yourself, and rails. (Should "news_path" expect an id parameter for the member, or is it the collection path? What is "a news"?)

Let's stick to calling them posts:

```
map.resources :posts, :as => "news", :singular => "news"
```

- Your route will be "/news"
- Your controller will be PostsController
- Your path helpers will be posts_path, post_path, edit_post_path, etc.

In other words, in all cases, you will call the resources "posts" but they will show up in the routes under "/news/*".

Comment: You are right. I now avoid names with the same singular and plural form. When I want to redefine them (or set non-english names), I add new inflections in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`